# The way to calculate Bitmap size?

Tags: android

I'm trying to find the size of my image but not to load into memory. I use the flowing code

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), R.drawable.icon, o);
int width1 = o.outWidt;     
int height1 = o.outHeight;
```

Now, I make some comparison:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
int width = icon.getWidth();
int height = icon.getHeight();
```

Why width, height is not equal to width1 and height1 ?

Comment: Which of those two is correct the size of the image? {width,height} or {width1,height1}

Comment: Original size of the image is width1 and height1.

Comment: The images are probably being resized based on dpi.. That's why I always load images with BitmapFactory.Options with inScaled = false. You should be able to check the two Bitmap's dpi and compare them. Check to see if they are they are different

Comment: What do you mean by "not load it into memory"? Just because you don't display it doesn't mean it's not in the memory.

Comment: It make sense. The image is resized based on dpi folder. 
My image is in drawable-hdpi folder, that mean I need to divide by 1.5f to reach the **icon** bitmap size, am I right?

Comment: dmon, I need only the size of the image, not full image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain this is because referencing that image from resources with decode the image comes pre scaled for density.

Checkout #1 here on the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going on, but it may be that BitmapFactory applies density scaling when actually returning a bitmap (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence)), but not when it is just decoding its size. (If this is what's going on, I'd consider filing a bug report.)

You can test this theory by moving your image from the `drawables` directory to `drawables-nodpi`.